# angular2 - how to set init value of select box

Tags: angular

I can load a select box with no issue track events etc.  What I cant do is to set the initial value.

```
[ { "id": "1", "name": "USD" }, { "id": "2", "name": "EUR" }]

<select [(ngModel)]="model_initials.currency" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" class="custom-select form-control">
            <option [ngValue]="i" *ngFor="let i of basecurrency" [ngModel]="{selected: model_initials.currency.id == 'i.id'}">{{i.name}}</option>
            </select>
```

Assume I want id:2 then how do I set?

I got this error:

platform-browser.umd.js:1900 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No value accessor for ''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below,

```
  <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
     <option *ngFor="let i of basecurrency"
             [value]="i"
             [selected]="model_initials.currency.id == i.id"
             >
             {{i.name}}
      </option>
  </select>
```

Comment: But $event.target.value returns [object Object] on the change event. What is that?  How do I get the new selected value?

Comment: It returns the entire object, depending upon what you need you can use the property of the object in the event.

Answer (score 1):

Use a tertiary conditional to set the 'selected' attribute.

Something like this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="model_initials.currency">
  <option *ngFor="let i of baseCurrency" [attr.value]="i" [attr.selected]="i.id === 2 ? true : null">{{ i.name }}</option>
 </select>
```